# Use array as index in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

So I have an array like so `['test', 'testtwo']`.

I wish to able to use that as an index for a dictionary like so `myDict['test']['testtwo']`.

Is this possible in python? Sorry for the short explanation.

EDIT:

```
exampleDict = {
  'test': {
    'testtwo': [
      '',
      ''
    ]
  }
}
```

And when doing some stuff in python I end up with the array `['test', 'testtwo']` and then need to use that to access `exampleDict['test']['testtwo']`. The keys change though and the number of keys in the array changes as well.

Comment: What is the bigger picture of what you want to achieve? a dictionary might be what you are looking for

Comment: yeah sorry both, I meant dictionary :/

Comment: You mean, [python dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: do you mean: `__list=['test', 'testtwo']; mydict = {__list: "foo" }`?

Comment: Can you show a sample dictionary?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use a loop, iterating the indices in the list and updating the "current" dict as you go:

```
>>> exampleDict = {'test': {'testtwo': [ '', '']}}
>>> d = exampleDict                               
>>> for x in idx:
...     d = d[x]
>>> d
['', '']
```

Or you could even use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) (`functools.reduce` in Python 3):

```
>>> reduce(lambda d, x: d[x], idx, exampleDict)
['', '']
```

You could use a similar approach to update the dict, but 1) you should use `setdefault` in case part of the index-list is not yet in the dict, and 2) you have to remove the last item from the list and use that as a regular index to the returned dictionary.

```
>>> idx2 = ['test', 'testthree', 'four']
>>> reduce(lambda d, x: d.setdefault(x, {}), idx2[:-1], exampleDict)[idx2[-1]] = "foo"
>>> exampleDict
{'test': {'testthree': {'four': 'foo'}, 'testtwo': ['', '']}}
```

In Python 3, you could make that line a bit easier to use using tuple-unpacking with `*`:

```
>>> *path, last = idx2
>>> reduce(lambda d, x: d.setdefault(x, {}), path, exampleDict)[last] = "foo"
```

Comment: This works great, but how can I then update the original dictionary?

Comment: Thank you so much @tobias_k the last bit works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a list for a dictionary key because lists are mutable, and mutable keys aren't allowed, but I think that what you want is to use each element of the list as an index. Without more context, it's not easy to say whether this is a good idea without proper checks, but:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b']
my_dict[my_list[0]][my_list[1]] # access at ['a']['b']
```

I have a feeling that whichever problem you wish to solve might be solved in a different way.

Comment: Like this, but the number of keys in `my_list` changes so I can't type it out manually as you did in the second line.

Comment: @MattCowley Right, but I hard-coded the list for the sake of example. You will need to pre-populate your dictionary while you build the list so key accesses to the dictionary are valid. I wrote my answer before you provided additional information thogh. tobias_k's answer looks good for the dictionary updates I described.